# Flutter: How to remove the divider lines in CupertinoDatePicker?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

[image: This view is achieved by creating custom CupertinoDatePicker]

While doing a coding walkthrough, I've never find a way to get rid of the divider lines.
How can I achieve this? For more info, I just created a new custom class by just copying the CupertinoDatePicker class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you copied the `CupertinoDatePicker` class just remove the border in the `_buildMagnifierScreen()` method in **picker.dart** from **/src/cupertino/**

```
/// Draws the magnifier borders.
  Widget _buildMagnifierScreen() {
    final Color resolvedBorderColor = CupertinoDynamicColor.resolve(_kHighlighterBorder, context);

    return IgnorePointer(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            // remove this attribute
            border: Border(
              top: BorderSide(width: 0.0, color: resolvedBorderColor),
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.0, color: resolvedBorderColor),
            ),
          ),
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
            height: widget.itemExtent * widget.magnification,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```